# How to run binary linux file in android?

Tags: android, linux, go, termux, gomobile

I have built an golang linux program without GUI, only input and output.

I want to build an android program to run it.

Do not use termux, because I want to embed it in the android program. (Users do not need to download the binary file.)

Or building a gomobile terminal app.(Not GL)

Answer (score 0):

You could build your Go code as a C library with an API that you can call using NDK (C layer) from your Android app.
It’s not easy but it is possible.

Alternatively you could build your Android app using Go (using Fyne or Gio for example).